# How to get data directly from XBee iolines

Tags: python, sensors, xbee

Hi I have XBee RF mode S2C which does not have internal storage to run micropython. So I need to get data from KY-001 sensor connected its iolines. With python library I didnt get anything just get_adc_value(ioline) function which seems doesnt do anything. I need to check sensor in local device for now .After I gonna use same solve to remote devices (I only use Python XBee library). Or exactly can I use Xbee  iolines directly to get data from sensor without external MCU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to interface to this 1-Wire sensor, it's intended for a microprocessor that can handle timing requirements and uses a tristate I/O line (IIRC).

You should be looking at temperature sensors with an analog voltage output (like this [TMP36](https://www.adafruit.com/product/165)) that you can tie to one of the analog inputs of the XBee, and then read that input with a remote `ATIS` for a single sample or `ATIR` for periodic sampling.